# Custom Button not displaying inside Layout (RelativeLayout and LinearLayout)

Tags: android

I've created three drawables for my custom button as shown in the code snippets below

**custom_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item 
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />

</selector>
```

**button_default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#fff" />

    <stroke 
        android:color="#f71b5d"
        android:width="0.5dp" />

    <corners 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

</shape>
```

**button_pressed.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#ebc2ce" />

    <stroke 
        android:color="#f71b5d"
        android:width="0.5dp" />

    <corners 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="7dp"
        android:left="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:top="7dp" />

</shape>
```

Here is the parent layout where I'm trying to use these drawables to create a custom button. The custom button is inside the LinearLayout

**fancy_card.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/fancy_card_bg">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**My problem**: The button inside the `LinearLayout` does not show up but when I remove my custom drawable from the background of the button, (`android:background="@drawable/custom_button"`), I can now see the button. If I remove the button from the LinearLayout and apply my `custom_button` drawable background to it, it works. I'm really confused of what is going on here.

[image]

Comment: <item 
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"
          android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />      Why you using  this can you explane ?

Comment: I want that when the button is **pressed**, then the **button_pressed.xml** drawable should be applied to the button and in any other case, then the **button_default.xml** drawable should be applied to it

Comment: why are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to the Button and define button background in your java file.

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);
```